# How to know if a javascript windows 8 app is closed by user

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a chat application on windows 8 using nodejs and socket.io... 
User can easily connect and disconnect from the chat at anytime but the problem is how can i detect that the user closes an app by ALT+F4 or Swipe or by any other mean so that i can disconnect the user as soon as he closes the app.

I have read somewhere in stackoverflow

```
When an app is closed it is first suspended. Microsoft recommends that you 
treat suspension as though the app will be closed because the OS may decide
to terminate the suspended app with no warning if there is resource contention.
```

So I have check the scenario by console.log() on app.oncheckpoint..it is not executed when the user closes or suspend an app but it is called when the user resumes the app.


Suggust me where to put the user disconnect function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of thing do you want to do when the user is disconnected?  If it involves sending commands to the server, then this logic belongs on the server side.  For example, what do you do when the internet connection fails?  Any disconnect logic won't get fired unless it is on the server.

So, my answer is:  put the logic on the server.  Either create a callback in node.js to detect the disconnect *or* have a heartbeat type of event that checks the user is still connected (simple ping send/responded to/from client)